# App that can help me manage my copy-paste

Tags: windows, text-editor, hyperlink, copy-paste, text

I talk to a lot of clients every day and answering FAQS could be a really hard time for me in the long term. What I do is copying from the txt file, alt-tab, paste. I want an app that can help me fasten my work, It should paste multiple clipboards where I don't have to alt-tab to open another file.

Something like this (basically, like a soundboard but text)

1. (FAQ answer #1) can be pasted with a hotkey(ex. shift+1)
2. (My Details) can be pasted with a hotkey(ex. shift+2)
3. (Personal links) can be pasted with a hotkey(ex. shift+3)

Comment: I'm not a Windows user myself, but I've heard of some software called [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) being capable of such things (and much more). For a quick overview, check [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey). Quote: "Using shortcuts to fill in frequently-used file names or other phrases" – that should meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ)** is an open-source, gratis, cross-platform tool that can do exactly what you want (along with ***many*** other things!).

You can store pre-defined clips in lists, and even create tabs of lists.  You can then assign shortcut keys to paste (insert) items from those lists.

CopyQ can have a bit of a learning curve, but its power is extensive due to its support for [commands](https://github.com/hluk/copyq-commands) and scripting, as well as its flexible configuration UI.

As of this writing (2021 February), CopyQ is actively developed and maintained by Lukas Holecek.

Copyq is available here:
https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ

The documentation is available here:
https://copyq.readthedocs.io/

I give CopyQ an impressive 5 out of 5 lizards.

Comment: I am having a hard time learning how to use it, I cant assign shortcuts on a single clip. 
Is there any alternative like this more user friendly? I wish I have time to learn it but unfortunately, it's really frustrating for me

Comment: @Patrich I hear you. It does a have a learning curve, and can be frustrating at first.  It took me a while to love it, and I thought about deleting it a few times until I finally had enough time to learn how to use it effectively. I think AHK (AutoHotKey) will also do what you want, but it has a bit of a learning curve too. There are some much simpler alternatives. I'm pressed for time right now, but I'll make a note to see if I can find something simpler to get running for you. Over the years, I've definitely come across a few simple tools to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor, FOSS and cross-platform. It has Python API so making the small plugin for your request is not hard.

You ask to paste some text via a hotkey - OK, CudaText plugin can give command, 3 commands for 3 items. So calling "Plugins / YourCommand / Copy 1st" will copy to clipboard the text `(FAQ answer #1)`. And you then paste it into another app via Ctrl+V. Hotkey for "Plugins / YourCmd / Copy 1st" can be added.

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would use [espanso](https://espanso.org), which is a *text expander*, so that depending on the answer you want to give, you would press one invocation or another.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CLCL - free clipboard app](https://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html). It allows you to have "templates".

For example, when I hit the CLCL hotkey, tap `T` for Template, I know if I press `6` it will paste my email address, and `5` will paste my phone number.

[image]

It's a little confusing to setup, but worth it, and totally portable so can run from USB.